# Android MapVIew: How detect movement from simple tap?

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a problem of that how to define when you haVe movement action and when you simply tap on a geopoint in MapView. Thing is that, when I just tap the following evEnts appear: ACTION_DOWN(1 fire), ACTION_MOVE(3 FIRES), ACTION_DOWN(1 fire). When I move the following events appear:ACTION_DOWN(1 fire), ACTION_MOVE(LOT FIRES), ACTION_DOWN(1 fire).

How to define it so and that it will not blok onTap function where is alertDialog for a geopoint?

What I have done but I mess a bit:

```
  @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    Log.i("Tapped? ", "TAP!");
    if (mOverlays.get(index) != null && !touchStarted) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        alert.showAlertDialog(mContext, item.getTitle(), item.getSnippet(), true);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; // Null GeoPoint
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

    Log.e("Touch", Integer.toString(event.getAction()));

    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        touchStarted = true;
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // movement: cancel the touch press

        touchStarted = false;

        if (event.getPointerCount() > 3)
        Log.e("Movement", "Yeee");
        return true;

    }
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity implement the onDoubleTapListener for finding the tap event and in the onTouchEvent as you have done, you will be able to handle the Move event. Use switch case for checking the move and other actions instead of if statement to improve the performance

For example if abc is your activity class then,

```
public class abc extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener{
    //Double tap listener

    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
       //your code
    }
}
```